# What difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser and custom ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I can add services with my own user definition as

```
Builder.Services.AddIdentity(Of ApplicationUser, ApplcationRole)...
```

than

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

And I can make the same operations with MS User definition - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser (Net Core 6)

```
Builder.Services.AddIdentity(Of IdentityUser, IdentityRole)...
```

than

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

But what exactly differences? What functions I need realize by own code instead MS code?

Comment: Why don't you want ms package?

Comment: `ApplicationUser` will inherit all the properties from `IdentityUser` and you can add your own (e.g. age, date of birth etc.)

Comment: @kanils_ MS Package is idiotic, (1) it require Microsoft SQL server, I don't use MS SQL Server, (2) Ms Package is double idiotic, it use EF Code First, 99,99% project impossible to implementation EF Code First, because 99,99% of project use existing data and existing SQL NON Microsoft server, Microsoft can not support EF Db first for other SQL and non SQL server except MS (3) MS Package use concrete and special MS User definition, existing sites and existing database usually building with own implementation of User without opinion what MS thinking how user definition need to define in DB.

Comment: None of those things are true. Identity does not require SQL Server. [For example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Instead of complaining about it, maybe go figure out what it does first. and if you don't like it, don't use it.

Comment: @DavidG, no-no-no, this is possible ONLY for new project with MS SQL server and with EF code first. Nobody has interest to this template in practice, with non MS SQL server, with non EF code first, with non MS User definition in db. MS Pattern is pattern for students, for new projects, for MS Server, it not interesting in practice at all.

Comment: @DavidG, Of course I use my own provider, but if I implement my user from MS user - I need definition in DB like MS User. 99,99% of sites use OWN implementation of user in DB, there are nothing AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetRolesClaims and other table in DB.

Comment: The docs literally tell you how to customise the framework to do whatever you like. The template is provided to get you started. Do you think MS should be providing a template for every single database out there? No, exactly. If you want to write your own identity provider then good luck, that is incredibly difficult. But you're on your own as I have better things to do. Have a good day.

Comment: Of course, I want to write own implementation of security. This is exactly my questions. And before MS adding his standard template IdentityUser - ANY programmers realize own login and security. It need usually no more than 3 line of code. You need only set up Authentication Cookie for browser and that's it. And this is reason why any ancient sites don't use Microsoft User definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replace default identity with MS database and MS user definition

```
Builder.
Services.
AddDefaultIdentity(Of ApplicationUser)()
```

to custom database (MySQL) with database first pattern (from existing user definition).

```
Builder.
Services.
AddIdentity(Of ApplicationUser, ApplcationRole).
AddDefaultUI().
AddDefaultTokenProviders().
AddUserStore(Of CustomUserStore).
AddRoleStore(Of CustomRoleStore)()
```

This is not a hard job. Need to realize only a couple of methods.

```
Public Interface ICustomUserStore(Of T As Class)
    Inherits IUserStore(Of T)
    Inherits IUserPasswordStore(Of T)
    Inherits IUserRoleStore(Of T)
    Inherits IUserEmailStore(Of T)
    Inherits IUserPhoneNumberStore(Of T)
    Inherits IUserAuthenticatorKeyStore(Of T) 'TwoFactor
    Inherits IUserTwoFactorStore(Of T)        'TwoFactor
    Inherits IUserTwoFactorRecoveryCodeStore(Of T)        'TwoFactor
    Inherits IUserLoginStore(Of T) 'download personal data
    'IUserPasswordStore
    Overloads Function SetPasswordHashAsync(user As T, passwordHash As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function GetPasswordHashAsync(user As T, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Overloads Function HasPasswordAsync(user As T, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Boolean)
    'IUserRoleStore
    Overloads Function AddToRoleAsync(user As T, roleName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function RemoveFromRoleAsync(user As T, roleName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function GetRolesAsync(user As T, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IList(Of String))
    Overloads Function IsInRoleAsync(user As T, roleName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Overloads Function GetUsersInRoleAsync(roleName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IList(Of T))
    'IUserEmailStore
    Overloads Function SetEmailAsync(user As T, email As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function GetEmailAsync(user As T, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Overloads Function GetEmailConfirmedAsync(user As T, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Overloads Function SetEmailConfirmedAsync(user As T, confirmed As Boolean, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function FindByEmailAsync(normalizedEmail As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of T)
    Overloads Function GetNormalizedEmailAsync(user As T, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Overloads Function SetNormalizedEmailAsync(user As T, normalizedEmail As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
End Interface
```

To form I have injected

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

And my ApplicationUser is not inherits from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser

All working fine, even including OWIN and 2FA. Working on VB.NET,   Linux platform and without MS database, without EF code First, with existing site databases.

[image: DefaultUI with custom story]